# MySQL - Unexpected behaviour of a LEFT JOIN (or maybe, I'm confused)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple SQL query running on MySQL, which doesn't return the results I expect. I would have sworn that it used to work, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

**UPDATED - Sample data for testing**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
);
INSERT INTO TABLE1(ID) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (
  parent_id INT,
  meta_key VARCHAR(100),
  meta_value VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE2(parent_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES 
    (1, 'John', 'some value'),
    (1, 'Sam', 'some value'),
    (1, 'Jill', 'some value'),
    (2, 'John', 'some value'),
    (3, 'Jill', 'some value')
;
```

The query is the following:

```
SELECT
  TABLE1.ID
FROM
  TABLE1
  LEFT JOIN
  TABLE2 ON
    (TABLE2.parent_id = TABLE1.ID) AND
    (TABLE2.meta_key IN ('JOHN', 'SAM', 'JILL'))
WHERE
  (TABLE2.meta_value IS NULL)
```

SQL Fiddle: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=157bfd6e-873e-4382-931c-0b53305575f2

The relationship between TABLE1 and TABLE2 is one to many. The purpose of the query would be to return all the rows in TABLE1 that don't have a corresponding match in TABLE2 for **any** of the values.

For example, if TABLE2 contains the following:

| parent_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | some value |
| 1 | Sam | some value |
| 1 | Jill | some value |
| 2 | John | some value |
| 3 | Jill | some value |

I would expect the query to return IDs 2 nd 3, because they don't have a match for Sam and Jill (ID 2), or John and Sam (ID 3). Instead, the query doesn't return any result. It looks like, since ID 2 matches John, and ID 3 matches Jill, the fact that these IDs don't match other values is ignored.

As mentioned, my objective would be to fetch all IDs that are missing **any** of the matches. If they do match one or more values, that's fine, but I need to know which ones are missing.

It feels like the solution is easy enough and I just can't see it.

Comment: please show also the cpntenzt of table1 for a full [mre]

Comment: It's not a `LEFT` -- because of `TABLE2.meta_key ...`

Answer (score 0):

So you want id's that *don't have* all of 'John', 'Sam' *and* 'Jill' among their meta_keys?  That can't be easily done with a join because you're matching individual rows against an *aggregated* result.

Instead, find all the id's that *do* match your keys criteria and *exclude* them:

```
select 
  id 
from table1 
where id not in 
( select parent_id 
  from table2 
  where meta_key in ( 'John', 'Sam', 'Jill' )
  group by parent_id 
  having count( * ) = 3 /* must have all three values */ 
) 
order by 1
```

Comment: `having count( * ) = 3  must have all three values `, it doesn't do what you are describing . It will get a result even for `John`,`John`,`John` or `John`,`John`,`Jill` and so on.  `having count( * ) = 3`  needs to be replaced with `having count(DISTINCT meta_key) = 3`

Comment: This could work partially, but I also need to know which values are not matching. That's why I used a JOIN. Without the WHERE clause, I would have expected to always get three entries for each ID, some of which would have NULL as a matched value.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  parent_id INT,
  meta_key VARCHAR(50),
  meta_value VARCHAR(50)
  );
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 'John', 'some value'),
(1, 'Sam',  'some value'),
(1, 'Jill', 'some value'),
(2, 'John', 'some value'),
(3, 'Jill', 'some value');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| parent_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | some value |
| 1 | Sam | some value |
| 1 | Jill | some value |
| 2 | John | some value |
| 3 | Jill | some value |

```
SELECT parent_id 
FROM test
-- WHERE meta_key IN ('Jill', 'John', 'Sam')
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT( /* DISTINCT */ meta_key ORDER BY meta_key) = 'Jill,John,Sam';
```

| parent_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IehnOrVB)

Pay attention - the names in the criteria list which is used in HAVING must be ordered strictly in the alphabetic order.

If `(parent_id, meta_key)` is not defined as UNIQUE then uncomment `DISTINCT`.

If `parent_id` which contains `meta_key` values other than ones in your criteria must be selected too then uncomment WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for parent_id that does not have a "complete" set of meta_values, something like:

```
select parent_id
from test
group by parent_id
having count(distinct meta_key) <> (select count(distinct meta_key) from test)
```

I borrowed @Akina 's [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FTLusfwx)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my own question. As I suspected, I was making a simple mistake, which was in front of my eyes.

What I'm trying to fetch is a list like the following:

1. ID 1 + John -> Value?
2. ID 1 + Sam-> Value?
3. ID 1 + Jill -> Value?
4. ID 2 + John -> Value?
5. ID 2 + Sam-> Value?
6. ID 2 + Jill -> Value?
7. ID 3 + John -> Value?
8. ID 3 + Sam-> Value?
9. ID 3 + Jill -> Value?

I need an entry for each ID + key value, whether there is a matching value or not. However, a simple LEFT JOIN is the wrong approach. The clause

```
LEFT JOIN
  TABLE2 ON
    (TABLE2.parent_id = TABLE1.ID) AND
    (TABLE2.meta_key IN ('John', 'Sam', 'Jill'))
```

means "*fetch the entries that match John, Sam or Jill. If one or more is found, return all the matches. If **none** is found, return one entry with NULL.*" Long story short, I'm using the wrong approach.

**Possible solution**

I found a way to fetch the data I needed by creating a "virtual table" and a second join. Example:

```
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
);
INSERT INTO TABLE1(ID) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (
  parent_id INT,
  meta_key VARCHAR(100),
  meta_value VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE2(parent_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES 
    (1, 'John', 'some value'),
    (1, 'Sam', 'some value'),
    (1, 'Jill', 'some value'),
    (2, 'John', 'some value'),
    (3, 'Jill', 'some value')
;

-- Fetch all the entries from TABLE1, with the value from TABLE2 
-- matching the meta_key from TABLE3
SELECT
  TABLE1.ID
  ,TABLE3.meta_key
  ,TABLE2.meta_value
FROM
  TABLE1
  JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 'John' AS meta_key
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Sam' AS meta_key
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Jill' AS meta_key
     ) AS TABLE3
     
  LEFT JOIN
  TABLE2 ON
    (TABLE2.parent_id = TABLE1.ID) AND
    (TABLE2.meta_key = TABLE3.meta_key)
ORDER BY
    TABLE1.ID;
    
-- Fetch all the entries from TABLE1 for which the value of one or
-- more of the meta_keys from TABLE3 is NULL in TABLE2
SELECT
  TABLE1.ID
  ,TABLE3.meta_key
  ,TABLE2.meta_value
FROM
  TABLE1
  JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 'John' AS meta_key
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Sam' AS meta_key
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Jill' AS meta_key
     ) AS TABLE3
     
  LEFT JOIN
  TABLE2 ON
    (TABLE2.parent_id = TABLE1.ID) AND
    (TABLE2.meta_key = TABLE3.meta_key)
WHERE
    (TABLE2.meta_value IS NULL)
ORDER BY
    TABLE1.ID;
```

SQL Fiddle: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=babf6d7d-5dbe-4b52-9316-2ea37645d551

This returns the result I need.